# how to get XML property using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I have XML file 
how can I get ayas or start or name ...Etc. where index = 1 or 2...Etc.

this is the code

```
<sura index="1" ayas="7" start="0" name="الفاتحة" tname="Al-Faatiha" ename="The Opening" type="Makkan" rukus="1" />
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the JavaScript you use to load the XML in? Or haven't you done that yet?

Comment: Refer this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624448/find-xml-attribute-values-with-javascript