# Find xml attribute values in a SOAP response with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, exchangewebservices

I'm working on an outlook web add-in, I use [GetItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getitem-operation-email-message) to get the ChangeKey from the Exchange Web Service SOAP response, a value I need to compose further requests. The problem is that so far I haven't been able to get that. I have followed [Find xml attribute values with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624448/find-xml-attribute-values-with-javascript) without success.
I'm not sure I'm able to use other external libraries since this is hosted in an office365 environment.

This is what I have been trying to do

```
var responseXML = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
' <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
'   <s:Header>'+
'       <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="3955" MinorBuildNumber="27" Version="V2018_01_08" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'+
'   </s:Header>'+
'   <s:Body>'+
'       <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">'+
'           <m:ResponseMessages>'+
'               <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">'+
'                   <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>'+
'                   <m:Items>'+
'                       <t:Message>'+
'                           <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADZh" ChangeKey="CQABA"/>'+
'                           <t:Subject>the email subject</t:Subject>'+
'                       </t:Message>'+
'                   </m:Items>'+
'               </m:GetItemResponseMessage>'+
'           </m:ResponseMessages>'+
'       </m:GetItemResponse>'+
'   </s:Body>'+
'</s:Envelope>';

xmlDoc = $.parseXML(responseXML),
$xml = $(xmlDoc),
$itemId = $xml.find("ItemId");
$itemId.each(function(index, element) { 
    if(element.attributes["ChangeKey"]) {
        console.log("ChangeKey :" + element.attributes["ChangeKey"].value);
    }
});
```

but `$itemId` does not return a collection, although I'm expecting only one item, i think it doesn't hurt to leave the iteration prepared.

https://jsbin.com/matagujeye/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-parse-xml-with-name-spaces) that I should include the name space and double escape the colons.

So the following code works:

```js
var responseXML = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
' <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
'   <s:Header>'+
'       <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="3955" MinorBuildNumber="27" Version="V2018_01_08" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'+
'   </s:Header>'+
'   <s:Body>'+
'       <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">'+
'           <m:ResponseMessages>'+
'               <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">'+
'                   <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>'+
'                   <m:Items>'+
'                       <t:Message>'+
'                           <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADZh" ChangeKey="CQABA"/>'+
'                           <t:Subject>the email subject</t:Subject>'+
'                       </t:Message>'+
'                   </m:Items>'+
'               </m:GetItemResponseMessage>'+
'           </m:ResponseMessages>'+
'       </m:GetItemResponse>'+
'   </s:Body>'+
'</s:Envelope>';

xmlDoc = $.parseXML(responseXML),
$xml = $(xmlDoc),
$itemId = $xml.find("t\\:ItemId");
$itemId.each(function(index, element) { 
    if(element.attributes["ChangeKey"]) {
        console.log("ChangeKey :" + element.attributes["ChangeKey"].value);
    }
});
```